# Can I install an AAV on a main house vent in my attic?

Tags: vent

I have a small camp house in upstate NY on a septic system. The main plumbing vent presently opens into our vented attic space. The attic has ridge and soffit vents, plus two approx 2sq ft vents one at each end.

Question, can I use an AAV and leave the vent as is in the attic?

Comment: Hi Ian, welcome. You should take the [Tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour), one of the rules of the site is to avoid general questions and opt to make questions as specific as possible. To that end, when you ask "can use AAV [...] as is [...] in the attic" are you concerned about code or are you just curious if it will function properly? If it's a code question, you'll need to give the specific jurisdiction you live in (town, state). You can click the link at the bottom of your question to edit your answer to clarify for which of these avenues you're seeking answers.

Comment: Is extending the plumbing vent thru the roof not an option?

Comment: Yes, why would you do that rather than making the vent correct (which seems like a simpler option anyway)?

Answer (score 2):

AAVs fail. Open vent pipes to the outside don't fail. I have doubts that ONLY having an AAV is acceptable in code, but I don't feel like searching for it right now *(someone else, feel free, I'll happily upvote, more points are nearly useless to me at this level of rep...)*

The fact that your septic was already improperly vented is not an encouraging sign.

Comment: As noted below in my answer, a quick google search for 'aav permitted in attic' finds this, [https://up.codes/viewer/texas/irc-2015/chapter/31/vents#P3114.4] - It looks to be allowable by Texas building code.

Comment: ...but it's not in Texas, it's in New York. Given that septic tanks *produce* gas, I expect that a system without at least one open vent to atmosphere will burp sewer gas back out the traps. At least until an AAV fails, as they do.

Comment: Edited for kindness: you stated "I have doubts that ONLY having an AAV is acceptable in code, but I don't feel like searching for it right now (someone else, feel free, I'll happily upvote, more points are nearly useless to me at this level of rep...)" ... if you meant "code in upstate ny" you should edit your post to clarify you want to see it from that region... The point you will not find in any code is that an aav without a vent is allowable, the aav won't work without a vent (not as it was intended), and in every case you will find requirement that vents to fresh air outside the building.

Comment: [up.codes/viewer/new_york/ipc-2015/chapter/9/vents#904.3] [www1.nyc.gov/site/buildings/codes/… ... you might just not be familiar with interpretting building codes? I mean no offense. It is clearly allowable because it is not forbidden across the United States, but a code compliant aav wherever its installed must have a vent stack that terminates above living space to outside air. Seems like that's clear in my answer, but maybe not to you? Who knows, after all you have so many points, guess I should defer to your judgment. Let me know

Comment: I think it might be helpful for you because it looks like an understanding you might be missing, and if not you maybe someone else, but the IBC is what's known as a model code. A jurisdiction adopts a model code to offset the liability and cost of writing their own code, they may amend the code to make it more stringent (usu. more prescriptive and explicit). The IBC is broadly adopted across the United States. Unless explicitly amended to disallow, the IBC allows aav's in attics (attic vented to code) *given connection to a stack terminating outside the building*

Comment: [Continuing from above because character limits] ... what you won't find in the United States of A in any jurisdiction is code allowing an aav in *any* configuration where it is not connected to a code compliant vent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can do anything. If you have some specific worry, like you're wondering if it's up to code, then you should update your question with a specific concern, and to that specific concern you get the typical 'it depends on local code.'

You should consider doing some homework of your own on a search engine of your choice first, rather than immediately going to a forum which, as this does, finds its top responders overwhelmingly not in the trades and when you get down to it if they don't cite certified sources they're just giving you an opinion.

So remember, it's your house, it's your choice how to proceed, and if the guy on the internet gives you advice you come to regret, that's a common and completely avoidable scenario... Further reading for you:

- NY specific codes, [https://up.codes/viewer/new_york/ipc-2015/chapter/9/vents#904.3]](https://up.codes/viewer/new_york/ipc-2015/chapter/9/vents#904.3%5D) and direct from the tap here: [https://www1.nyc.gov/site/buildings/codes/2014-construction-codes.page#plumb] (see section 9 for vents).
- [Click here for an example of a search result](https://www.jlconline.com/products-tools/kitchen/kitchen-bath-venting-with-air-admittance-valves_o), I used Google.com and searched for 'aav permitted in attic'.
- [Click here for another](http://www.inspectionnews.net/home_inspection/plumbing-system-home-inspection-and-commercial-inspection/38377-aav-vent-attic.html).
- [Click here for another](https://forum.nachi.org/t/hub-vents-in-attic/3959).
- A quick search finds this, [click here](https://up.codes/viewer/texas/irc-2015/chapter/31/vents#P3114.4): It looks to be allowable by Texas building code (it is typical for for small poor towns and unincorporated areas to adopt a State Code without amendments).

This is not intended to be condescending, the next guy who reads this post might be 75 years old and not computer savvy, or someone like you who just didn't think about it.

[This article](https://www.startribune.com/air-admittance-valves/497667461/) explains how Studor vents work, and this diagram is particularly informative.:
[image: AAV's need to be connected to an outlet for the sewer gasses to flow out, otherwise they will function practically as a cap as there will not be any way to displace the gasses]. The typical way to deal with your situation is to connect all the vents into one central stack that runs through the roof.

Work early in the day in your attic before it heats up, or circulate cool air, or work in short trips.